# print function in Python

Tags: python, printing

I need some help in Python, to print:

I have:

> input =[(3, 'x1'), (5, 'x3'), (2, 'x2')]

need to print, in this form:

```
x1=3 x2=2 x3=3
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a need to be the list of x's sorted?

Answer (score 9):

```
print ' '.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for (v, k) in input)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for x,y in input: 
    print "%s=%s" % (y, x),
```

Comment: or `print ' '.join("%s=%d" % (y, x) for x,y in input)`

Answer (score 1):

```
input =[(3, 'x1'), (5, 'x3'), (2, 'x2')]     
for i,j in input:
   print("{}={}".format(j,i),end=" ")
```

***print j,i because second one will come before first. Format is function used to print the values. If u want to print above in different lines rather than single then remove end=" "***